# Strange view of row filter in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui-grid

I have a problem with the row filtering method of my Kendo UI Builder grids.

When I'm setting the filterable property to `"row"` or `"menu, row"` then the grid displays the following row filters.

[image]

You can see, that there is no input area and the filter itself looks broken.

Here is my code for setting the filterable mode in `controller.public.js`.

```
this.$components.KDGrid.options.filterable = {
    mode: "row"
};
```

The grid is made by the Kendo UI Builder Version 2.0.0.87 by Progress.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! 
If you modify the filterable mode, than you also have to modify the filter options.

[Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.filterable.cell)

```
this.$components.KDGrid.options.columns["0"].filterable = {
        cell: {
            showOperators: false,
            operator: "gte"
        }
    };
```